# Centering a Google Maps marker over its position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've created a Google Maps JavaScript embed with a [RichMarker](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html) placed at the arbitrary coordinate *50.85, 4.35*. I've marked this coordinate by approximation with a green dot in the screenshot below.

[image: Marker is placed above its LatLng location.]

As you can see, the content of the marker is placed above the coordinate. This is not the behavior I'm looking for. Instead, I want the marker to be centered over the coordinate, as shown here:

[image: Marker is centered over its position.]

Is there an easy way to enforce this type of placement using the standard Google Maps API, a plugin or jQuery? I'm using v3 of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the anchor for the RichMarker to be the center of the image (not the bottom center).

Comment: Found it, thanks! For future reference: you have to define the property `anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE` on the marker. I found an example of it being used [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/io-2010-bootcamp/richmarker.html?r=204).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the infobox plugin to make this alot easier.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Comment: It looks like the box is now anchored to the coordinate at its [top left corner](http://i.imgur.com/2uUu9.png). I could use a fixed *pixelOffset* to center the box over the marker, but I don't know the dimensions of the infobox at this stage.

Comment: Id suggest you dont change the dimensions of the infobox anyway, would make for better UX.

Comment: I'm all for it, but is there a way to center an infobox marker over its position?

Comment: Dont think so only because its been designed that way.

Comment: Depending on size of your project, you could always directly edit the plugin to force infobox position to be LatLng position.